# Building Android library (aar) with google endpoint client library

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I am trying to create an android library for my app.
My library contains a backend project

Gradle for my android library

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.0.3"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(path: ':xxx_Backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')

}
```

I have pushed this library to maven central.

However when I access this library in my android app I get the following error that

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:xxxx_backend.xxxxapi.model.xxDS
```

Android app gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "in.test.bankdemo"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'xxxsdk:app:0.0.3'
}
```

Please let me know how can I solve this issue. I have tried fataar and creating jars but nothing seems to work.